# how to remove distance from processbar to parent element

Tags: css, html, progress-bar, progress

I use the HTML5 element `<progress>` to create an progress bar.

Now I like to add an related text in top of the bar with nearly no space between progress bar and the related text. But: there is always a space between the bar and his next neighbour element, as shown here:

http://jsfiddle.net/ht06d49k/2/

```
<div>
    <div>progressing something</div>
    <div class="smallProgressBar">Text related to progress...</div>
    <div>
        <progress class="smallProgressBar" id='p' max='100' value='45'>
        </progress>
    </div>
```

```
.smallProgressBar {

    width: 100%;
    font-size: 0.5em;
}
```

Using the chrome developer tools I see, that this space is generated from the progress bar parent element. The `<div>`

But:

The first tow  `<div>` elements are much closer without an space. But between the 2nd and 3rd `<div>` element there is a space.

What could be the reason for that? And how to remove that space?

Btw: moving the progressbar-div some pixels up is not an option for me.. like this:

```
<div style="position:relative;top:-5px;">
    <progress class="smallProgressBar" id='p' max='100' value='45'>
    </progress>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `line-height: 0` to the `div` containing the `progress`. For example:

```
<div class="progress-bar">
<progress class="smallProgressBar" id='p' max='100' value='45'></progress>
</div>

.progress-bar {
    line-height: 0;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ht06d49k/4/).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `:after` :pseudo-element instead.

Absolutely positioned :pseudo-element.

```css
.smallProgressBar {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
#small {
  position: relative;
}
#small:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: 'Text related to progressbar...';
  top: -1px;
  font-size: 6px;
  color: red;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>progressing something</div>
  <div id="small">
    <progress class="smallProgressBar" id='p' max='100' value='45'></progress>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Relatively positioned :pseudo-element.

```css
.smallProgressBar {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
#small {
  position: relative;
}
#small:before {
  position: relative;
  content: 'Text related to progressbar...';
  top: 7px;
  font-size: 6px;
  color: red;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>progressing something</div>
  <div id="small">
    <progress class="smallProgressBar" id='p' max='100' value='45'></progress>
  </div>
</div>
```